# python клиент-серверное приложение

Tags: python, сервер, клиент

Есть у кого клиент серверное-приложение для просмотра файлов. т.е. клиент отправляет путь , сервер получает этот путь, и отправляет все то, что написано в файле. Было бы идеально, если пользователь отправлял, например 1 => нужно получить данные из ФАЙЛА
Что есть 
client

```
import socket

IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 1005
buffersize = 65535

s = socket.socket()
s.connect((IP, PORT))
print("Соединение с сервером " + IP + ":" + str(PORT) + " установлено.\n")

while True:
    print("Команды:")
    print("1 Log file посмотреть")
    if pckType == 1:
        data = input("Введите путь: ")
        pckSend = chr(pckType) + data
        s.send(bytearray(pckSend, 'utf-8'))
        pckRecv = s.recv(buffersize).decode("utf-8")
s.close()
print("Соединение закрыто.")
```

server

```
import time
import socket
import threading
from  test_for_log import openning

IP = ''
PORT = 1005
backlog = 50
buffersize = 65535

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((IP, PORT))
s.listen(backlog)
print("Порт " + str(PORT) + " прослушивается...")


def new_connect(sock, addr):
    def send(pckData):
        sock.send(bytearray(pckData, 'utf-8'))

    last_message = chr(0)
    try:
        while True:
            data = sock.recv(buffersize).decode("utf-8")  # получаем данные
            if data == '': break

            pckType = ord(data[0])  # первый байт - тип сетевого пакета

            if pckType == 1:  # 01 - высветить ему лог файл
                a = data[1:]
                openning(a)
                print(addr[0] + " Log file высветить")
sock.close()
        print("Соединение " + addr[0] + " закрыто")
while True:
    sock, addr = s.accept()
    print("Новое соединение от " + addr[0])

    threading.Thread(target=new_connect, args=(sock, addr,)).start()  # создаем новый поток
```

test_for_log

```
import re

# В этом списке собираются подстроки для проверки через in
from typing import List, Any

bad_line_parts = [
    'Standby redo logfile selected for thread'
]
bad_reg_exprs = [
    re.compile('[A-Z][a-z]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d{4}'),
    # здесь дополнить другими регулярными выражениями, если потребуется
]


def is_fine_line(line):
    return (not any(bad_line_part in line
                    for bad_line_part in bad_line_parts) and
            not any(bad_reg_expr.match(line)
                    for bad_reg_expr in bad_reg_exprs))


def openning(message):
    with open(message, 'r') as log_file:
        for line in log_file.readlines():
            if is_fine_line(line):
               print(line)
```

На сервере получаю, как отправить это клиенту не знаю
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: За поиском готовых решений вам на GitHub. За поиском решения по заказу вам к фрилансерам. За поисков ответов на общие/тривиальные вопросы вам в учебники. Здесь же *помогают*, отвечают на *конкретные* технические вопросы по тому, что *конкретно* не получилось у вас. Если у вас нет каких-то вразумительных набросков своего решения, то и нам помогать не с чем.

Comment: Ничего не нашел на GitHub, а свое не получается

Comment: Так что же **конкретно** не получается? Сделать клиент и передавать запрос? Сделать сервер и получать запрос? Считывать данные из файла? Отправлять данные обратно клиенту? Разбивайте крупные задачи на *конкретные* подзадачи, и у каждой найдёте сотни вариантов решений в интернете. Если на это пока не хватает навыков, то идите читать учебники, там масса практических примеров от маленьких задач до крупных проектов.

Comment: Отправить данные клиенту

Comment: Ну вот, другое дело `(:` Почему именно `socket`? А не нормальный HTTP, `Flask` на сервере и `requests` на клиенте? И кстати, незачем подгружать не используемый `typing`.

Answer (score 1):

server

```
import multiprocessing.connection, threading, socket, logging

def server_start(port: int, ip_list: tuple, authkey: bytes) -> dict:
    servers = {}
    for ip in ip_list:
        ip_port = (ip, port)
        t = lambda ipp=ip_port: worker(ipp, authkey, work=job, servers=servers)
        servers[ip_port] = threading.Thread(target=t, daemon=False)
        servers[ip_port].start()
    return servers

def worker(ip_port: (str, int), authkey: bytes, work: 'callable', servers: dict, error='') -> None:
    while servers.get(ip_port):
        with multiprocessing.connection.Listener(ip_port, authkey=authkey) as listener:
            with listener.accept() as conn:
                try:
                    conn.send_bytes(work(conn.recv()))
                except:
                    conn.send(error)
                    logging.error(conn, exc_info=True)

def job(file_name: str) -> bytes:
    with open(file_name, 'rb') as f:
        return f.read()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    h = socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())  # ('DESKTOP-GMS1C57', [], ['192.168.1.44', '17...'])
    servers = server_start(port=8080, ip_list=tuple(h[2]), authkey=b'secret')
    print(servers)  # {('192.168.1.44', 8080): <Thread(Thread-1, started 11420)>, ('17...', 8080): <Thread(Thread-2, started 4364)>}
```

client

```
import multiprocessing.connection

def remote_file_text(file_name: str, ip_port: (str, int), authkey: bytes) -> bytes:
    with multiprocessing.connection.Client(ip_port, authkey=authkey) as conn:
        conn.send(file_name)
        try:
            return conn.recv_bytes()
        except:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f'{ip_port} {file_name}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file_name = 'c:\\Recovery.txt'
    ipp = ('192.168.1.44', 8080)
    b = remote_file_text(file_name=file_name, ip_port=ipp, authkey=b'secret')  # b'my text'
    text = b.decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')  # "my text"
    print(text)
```

Comment: А чтобы это работало клиент и сервер должны быть на одной машине, верно?

Comment: нет, конечно можно и на разных, правда правильность кода не проверял, упростил свой имеющийся скрипт

Comment: Интересное решение работы :)